# How does apt-btrfs-snapshot work?

Tags: btrfs

I read [on the planet](http://mvogt.wordpress.com/2011/03/10/apt-btrfs-snapshot/) that `apt-btrfs-snapshot` would be available for Natty. The brief description of what it does sounds very nice:

> it will automatically create filesystem snapshot (of everything but /home) when apt installs/removes/upgrades. With the apt-btrfs-snapshot cli app its easy to list/remove/rollback the snapshots

But before I convert my entire life to `btrfs` for the sole purpose of gaining a built-in backup system, can anybody tell me how `btrfs`'s snapshots work. To my layman's brain, it sounds like this would eat a devastating amount of disk space if you're taking snapshots every time you install or upgrade something (I do this more than once a day).

I assume the system is smarter than I'm allowing it but I really don't know. How do the snapshots work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know `apt-btrfs-snapshot`, but from what I read rapidly in the code, it simply use the btrfs snapshot feature before `apt`'s actions.

`btrfs` uses [a lot of B-trees](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Btrees#FS_Trees) to hold data. Duplication is kept to minimum (not even using hardlink, but copy-on-write). Read: "it will use as much *more-memory* that you delete data outside /home".

EDIT:

After reading the code, `apt-btrfs-snapshot` have some problems. For example:

- it makes big assumptions: your `btrfs` must have specific subvolume's name (your root subvolume must be named "`@`")
- if your `/home` and `/var/lib` are on the same subvolume as your root `/`, they will also be snapshotted.

Comment: When I installed using btrfs, these things were setup by default - home was mounted on a subvolume, and root had the special name.  It's true that if you transitioned an existing ext4 install to btrfs you would not necessarily have everything nicely set up for this.